# How to fix Unprotected broadcast receiver warning?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, warnings

I get the following warning from my broadcast receiver:

This broadcast receiver declares an `intent-filter` for a protected broadcast action string, which can only be sent by the system, not third-party applications. However, the receiver's `onReceive` method does not appear to call `getAction` to ensure that the received Intent's action string matches the expected value, potentially making it possible for another actor to send a spoofed intent with no action string or a different action string and cause undesired behavior.

How can I fix it?

MY code:

```java
public class NotifayTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the explanation of the warning says it all, doesn't it? Let's assume you are filtering for `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`:

```
if (!Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    // Maybe log something
    return
}
```